# Need help with PTC heater EDITED

Tags: automotive, fan, heater, ptc

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHYpPD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. CircuitLab schematic by @Transistor for OP to edit.*

I have built a heater from a PTC heater with a couple of fans on top and power from a 13.7 Ah lithium battery (with built in BMS.) The PTC has a power save function which lowers power consumption after reaching around X degrees Celsius. When that happens the fans also lower speed by a lot, which is the problem I want to fix. I want the fan to be able to keep running at full speed and the PTC to keep the power save function.

Everything runs on 12 V.

I’m guessing I need some sort of divider or regulator to give the PTC and the fans separate power but still from the same battery.

How do I make this work? What do I need?

To add some clarity I'll add a drawn schematic.

I can't get it to work with the bench power supply at all, the relay just clicks on and off again. The power supply changes from CV to CC for half a second. The bench power supply  is set to 12 volt CV.

With the battery it works but when the PTC gets hot enough it lowers the power together with the fans resulting in the fans lowering speed.

I want to make the fan keep its speed while the PTC lowers by itself.

Added a few more pictures
1st are wires from ptc heater
2nd are the fan cables + and -
3rd is the relay switch ports

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic how you connected everything. From your description it sounds like you wired your PTC and fan in series, but hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @makkkis, I've added a schematic for you to edit. If your bench power supply is going into consant current mode it means you are drawing more power than it can supply - probably due to a wiring error.

Comment: hmm i dont understand this schematic,  wiring like this leaves one polarity on the ptc not connected and2 ports not used on the relay. the relay has + - input and + - output. The ptc has no + output. Maybe im stupid or tired but im still learning.

Comment: Can you give a datasheet for the PTC?

Comment: What is the purpose of the relay?  If you want the fans to run at full speed at all times, they should be connected directly to the power supply.

Comment: I cant seem to find a datasheet for it, bought it off amazon:
https://www.amazon.se/-/en/Electric-Insulated-Ceramic-Thermostatic-Heating/dp/B097PLKW8J        The purpose is being able to activate the heater/fan from a distance. Yes that was my original plan but the fans lower speed at the same time as the heater reaches its temperature when plugged directly to the powersource together with the heater.